# Regex for double in lex

Tags: regex, lex, flex-lexer

I'm writing calculator in lex and need a regex for recognizing doubles. How should it be written? It should be something like `[[0 + [0-9][0-9]*].[0-9]+] + [1-9][0-9]*`, but can't make it work in lex.

Sample inputs are any double or integer(will be converted to double)

Comment: Can you give some example inputs? What would you like your pattern to match and what do you want it *not* to match?

Comment: Flex-lexer for the lexical analyzer; Flex is for the ADobe/Apache UI Framework. This is mentioned in the tag hints for 'Flex'.  Please be aware when tagging; thank you

Comment: I'm sorry. I accidently included it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few problems:

1. Spaces are significant in regular expressions: remove them.
2. Square brackets (`[]`) denote a character class, not a grouping.  Use parentheses for grouping.
3. The period character (`.`) matches anything, and I believe that your intent is
   to match only the period character (decimal point), so you need to escape it with a
   backslash.

So change your regular expression to

```
((0+[0-9][0-9]*)\.[0-9]+)+[1-9][0-9]*
```

and debug from that point.

Also, I'm not sure that you understand the difference between the plus character (`+`), which means one-or-more repetitions, and the pipe character (`|`), which means either-or.